# Error on compiling file in sublime text on macOS

Tags: c++, macos, sublimetext

I am new to programming and have just installed this text editor on a friend's suggestion.

I don't know what went wrong but I get this error on building a simple C++ code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    

    int a;
    cin>>a;
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
        cout<<"HEllo World!";

    return 0;
}
```

The error is as follows:-

> ld: can't write output file to '/Users/vihangawagholkar/Desktop/dsa/test' because that path is a directory
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> [Finished in 234ms with exit code 1]
> [shell_cmd: g++ "/Users/vihangawagholkar/Desktop/dsa/test.cpp" -o "/Users/vihangawagholkar/Desktop/dsa/test" && "/Users/vihangawagholkar/Desktop/dsa/test"]
> [dir: /Users/vihangawagholkar/Desktop/dsa]
> [path: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin]

Comment: Seems you have a linker error so Either your #include <iostream> is not in a global path  so  your compiler does not know where to find it . 

locate iostream.h file and link it properly

Comment: You have a directory where your cpp file is with the same name as the file without the extension. You'll need to remove that directory or rename your file to something else to fix the conflict.

Comment: I understand the problem but how do I go about fixing it, is there a specific way to change paths in macOS?